# What is the full form of LDC in opcode

Tags: jvm, opcode

What is the full form of 'LDC' in opcode?

I find the doc, but there is no answer:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ldc

I learn it from jvm, I know it also in x86-opcode. So what is it history?

please, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As the linked documentation says, it loads a constant from the constant pool (through the index) and then pushes that on the stack.